# R file in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Why R file does not generate in android studio? There's no any error in xml file. When I build the project it gives error message as below.

> Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'. Error:(2)
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Users\admin_2\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 1

### Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
int counter;
Button add,sub;
TextView display;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter = 0;
    add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TvDisplay);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;
            display.setText("Your total is" + counter);

        }

    });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter--;
            display.setText("Your total is" + counter);

        }

    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

### View Layout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="396dp"
        android:text="your total is 0"
        android:textSize="80px"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/TvDisplay"/>


    <Button android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="add_one"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/bAdd"
        />

    <Button android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="subtract_one"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/bSub"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admin_2.myapplication" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Show the code/files relevant to this error please.

Comment: I have added my code below. Can you please check that?

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as it sounds, R.java will not be generated if you have an error inside your xml.

The reason you have an error is because your syntax for how you're referring to that style is wrong.

It should be:

`@android:style/<name>`

Comment: You mean the error is here in this code. @android:style/<name>   I cann't find the place where this code should replace with.

Comment: Look at your code for this TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse and see if you can find it. Then replace it.

Comment: I still didn't understand. I have added my code below. Can you please check it?

Comment: Its not java, its xml. Please update your post, don't post an answer.

Comment: Not the XML I am referring to. You should be looking at your AndroidManifest.xml for your application. You should focus on learning what data means what and how its used. Specifically its tied to configuration changes for an Activity.

Comment: I replece this         android:theme="@style/myapplication" >  in the manifest file. But it did not work. Error remains.

Comment: You need to search all your code to find 'TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse' then fix that. Sorry, I made a mistake, its not going to be in your AndroidManifest.xml its going to be in one of your layouts.

Comment: Yes I find it. But how to fix it? It resides in v23\values-v23.xml file. But I don't know how to fix it. It comes under the build folder.